# Angular - Dynamic Component - Compiler Issue - Memory Leak?

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, angular-compiler

I am trying to create a dynamic component. [Here](http://embed.plnkr.co/EVFglgkp24hkRkpxrEGe/) is the sample in plunker. http://embed.plnkr.co/EVFglgkp24hkRkpxrEGe/
Everything is working but there is a memory leak.

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19997) is the github ticket https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19997

Dynamically created components are getting destroyed, **but the component which created the dynamic component is not getting destroyed**. In other words, **The component which compiled the dynamic component is not getting destroyed**.

In the above example, if we navigate back and forth between "Home" and "Dynamic Page" and take a snapshot of memory in chrome, you can see that the components suppose to be destroyed are still there as depicted below.

[image]

For the testing purpose, I even tried commenting the bellow lines, but still the issue exists.

```
      let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);
      let ngMdlRef = ngMdlFac.create(injector);
      let cmpFactory = ngMdlRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicHtmlComponent);
      this.cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(cmpFactory);
```

The moment I call

> this.compiler.compileModuleAsync

The creator component is not getting destroyed at all. until then there is no issue.

Can you please someone help on this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, the problem with the memory leak is caused by the manual module compilation and instantiation. If you take a look at the retainers of the `MyCreatorComponent` you can see that functions `DynamicHtmlComponent` and `DynamicModule` hold the reference to the parent `MyCreatorComponent` function through context.

[image]

These are the objects with the shortest distance to GC root, so they are most likely the objects responsible for memory leaks. The question is why they are not removed? The answer is that Angular heavily caches everything it creates and it happens in your case as well. Just through a quick look I've identified at least two caches that retain the references.

#### First

```
export class JitCompiler {
  private _compiledHostTemplateCache = new Map<Type, CompiledTemplate>();
```

When you call `this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(DynamicModule)` Angular adds `CompiledTemplate` with the key `DynamicHtmlComponent` to this cache and never clears it.

#### Second

```
const _tokenKeyCache = new Map<any, string>();
```

When you call `var ngMdlRef = ngMdlFac.create(...)` Angular adds `DynamicHtmlComponentFactory` to  this caches and never deletes  it.

Notice  that these caches are `Maps`, not `WeakMaps` so as long as there's no explicit call to `.delete()` the objects will be retained.

Comment: While we can run `compiler.clearCache` to clear `compiledHostTemplateCache` and other stuff cached within compiler,  we can't clear `tokenKeyCache`.

Comment: @yurzui, yeah, and these are only the two I've found. I think there are others

Comment: Angular will add all tokens in `tokenKeyCache`  for providers every time it executes compilation I think it is because that compiler is supposed to be run only once

Comment: Also we need to enable prod mode

Comment: @yurzui, yeah, it seems we won't be able to avoid memory leaks with this approach

Comment: He already posted issue on github. Will see what they can answer

Comment: @yurzui, can you put a reference here?

Comment: `ComponentFactory`, `DynamicModule` and `DynamicHtmlComponent` are added to tokenKeyCache

Comment: @yurzui, didn't want to go deeper into this :)

Comment: Ok, i don't mind. As you have already said `Angular heavily caches everything it creates`

Comment: @yurzui, I was just curios enough to make use of `Retainers` section to identify objects holding a reference to the `MyCreatorComponent`

Comment: Thank you @AngularInDepth.com & yurzui for helping me to understand this issue in detail. As yurzui mentioned, I created ticket in github, lets see... special thanks to AngularInDepth.com for your articles. I gone through some of your articles when I was searching for dynamic components. :-)

Comment: @Rajkumar, glad I could help, good luck! I also posted the same answer on github :) Follow angluarindepth.com publication for more great articles to come

Comment: @Rajkumar, don't forget you can accept my answer if it answered you question completely :)